# How to calculate the Big O notation of following equations?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

1. This is a recursive formula:

E(r,n) = (E(r-1,n-1)-E(r,n-1))^2 + E(r,n-1)  r<=n

Please show the process of getting the Big O as well.

2. summation from i=0 to r, (r-i)*(n choose i)*(p^(n-i) * (1-p)^i)

I think calculating the Big O to this equation equals to calculating Big O of:

summation from i=0 to r, (n chose i)

Is this correct?

Please show the process of getting the Big O as well.

Comment: What are the base cases for `E(r, n)`?

Comment: Based on my preliminary findings, I am getting something which looks like `O(r ^ n-1)` but I cannot prove this (I studied `E(r,n)` using `R` for a while).

Comment: This reminds me of Ramsey numbers.

Comment: Is r scaling with r ? For the second one if r < n/2 you can upperbound the sum by r * n choose r and then use Stirling approximation to estimate the binomial term. Net result is O(r n!/ (n-r)! r!) = O(r n^n/ ((n-r)^(n-r) r^r) ). If you write r = xn you get O(r  (1-x)^(-n(1-x)) x^(-nx) )  If r > n/2 then this is O(2^n).

Comment: base cases is given that E(0,0) = 0, E(1,1) =1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assming that I am understanding the problem correctly and you want the time complexity of a program that does each of those things:

1. What are the base cases for that recursion? Let's assume that E(0,0) is the base case, E(r,0) is a linear recursion till E(0,0) and r > n. Imagine that we form a recursion tree. We would get that each level of would have the call the function with the n from the previous level minus one, since the function always call itself with n-1. Now analysing the tree and separating it we get:

   - A triple recursion until n = 0;
   - After n = 0, we get a branches of linear recursion (a is dependent on n and r)

Analising the triple recursion, we can find it's complexity by various methods (generating functions, master's, etc) but lets use a simpler method. Let's assume that each node uses one time unit. We know that each level has 3 times the nodes of the level before, that the first level has one node and that the tree has n levels, and that the total time is the summation of all nodes. So we get that 
TotalTripleTime = Summ(0, n) of 3^k
This can be given by the closed formula for a geometric progression so:
(1-3^n+1)/-2 which is O(3^n)

The amount of is a little harder to calculate due to the complex recursion and I dont have alot of time, maybe I'll try it later.

2. Assuming that r is smaller than n, the we simply have that O(r * O(combinatations)) Assuming that calculating the a simple combinatorial using the closed formula is O(n), we get O(n*r).

Comment: What if the base case is given that E(0,0) = 0, E(1,1) =1?

Comment: Since in the recursion formula, E(r, n-1) is called, for every r > 1 you would still need a recurrent (or not) formula for E(r, 0).

Comment: I just edited the question, could you look at it again please? thanks!

Comment: Just did, let me show an example of what I am trying to say:
What if I call E(6,1)? One of the recurrent calls would be E(6,0). How do I calculate this?

Comment: once r>n, the program should quit. I am sorry that I didn't mention this.

Comment: And I edited question 2 on the top as well.  And I have a question I think summation of all nodes should be O(n^2), could you tell me why you think it's O(3^n)?